# Python Split a string by diffrent . full stops

Tags: python, string, split

hey i want to be able to change my string being split at say the third full stop or the 2nd  here is my code

```
file = "hey there. this is some demo code. will you nice people please help me."
```

i want to split the string **after** the 2nd full stop so it will look like

```
"hey there. this is some demo code."
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: i dont understand that documention

Comment: `'.'.join(file.split('.')[:-2])`

Comment: @RobertStenhouse  - If you want to learn programming you HAVE to learn how to understand the docs. They are really simple and well documented. Moreover you have 1000s of questions on SO which could help you out with this trivial problem

Comment: i can work java docs fine , the python hower i cant seem to understand probally as its all togather it makes it harder to read , thank you though for your orignal post

Comment: Look at the `maxsplit` argument of the `str.split` method. Then you can `join` your "stops" into a string. The code to execute: `' '.join(file.split(' ', 2))`

Comment: ahh that sort if make sense thank you eli will look into that

Answer (score 0):

```
".".join(file.split(".")[2:])
```

or

```
file.split(".",2)[2:]
```

These use `str.split()` ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)), `str.join()` ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)), and slices ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)). There's no reason to use loops or regex for this.

Comment: awsome im putting that into a vraible to print and it saying its a list , is there a way of just taken out the bits before the 2nd full stop and putting that as a diffrent string

Comment: just tried it and its not cuttong off after 2nd ful stop when i print it

Comment: Note that this only splits on `'.'`, not all full stops.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
readf = open("split.txt")

for line in readf:

  a=line.split(".")

readf.close()

print (a[:2])
```

Basically you store the line in a and split it on "." and then use a subsequence which you can use however you like.
e.g. a[2:3] gives u the secound and third line while a[:3] gives you all three.

Comment: i just turned off my pc will try in morning thank you

Comment: Note that this only splits on `'.'`, not all full stops.

Comment: @RobertStenhouse hmm I may be mistaken. I was under the impression that a full stop was any sentence-ending punctuation (e.g. `'.'`, `'!'`,`'?'`).

Comment: oh no a full stop is . you dont use one if diffrent punctuation is there

Comment: user37. .. is there a way to do that with a variable that is a syring not from a file

Comment: Doesn't this only do this for the last line in the file?

Comment: @RobertStenhouse `string.split(".")[:2]` where `string` is a variable containing a string.

Answer (score -1):

A rough way to do it would be to use a counter and loop through the string, adding every character until the stopping limit is reached.

```
firstString = ""
secondString = ""
stopsAllowed = 1
stopsFound = 0
for i in range(0,len(file)):
  if file[i] == ".":
    stopsFound += 1
  if stopsFound <= stopsAllowed:
    firstString += file[i]
  else:
    secondString += file[i]
```

Comment: Very unnecessary and complex. Would down vote but that costs me rep.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how it is complex